# What does "a satisfactory conclusion the UN Security Councilˈs consideration of this matter" mean?

Tags: sentence-meaning

> There would be additional steps in between the initial measures and the final step, including, among other things, addressing the UN Security Council resolutions, *with a view toward bringing to a satisfactory conclusion the UN Security Councilˈs consideration of this matter.*

For context: [here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCgQFjAA&url=http://www.cnn.com/2013/11/24/world/meast/iran-deal-text/&ei=z3n-UsCUNdTioASX5YDgBg&usg=AFQjCNEIwFOhgjyMpmnyiDQ69m7kUWRRFw&sig2=ZK7s5xpBL4bZEq-qLplI-Q)

1)Is there any redundancy in "including, among other things"?

2)This part seems a bit odd: *with a view toward bringing to a satisfactory conclusion the UN Security Councilˈs consideration of this matter.*
What is the apostrophe s contradiction for?

Comment: For question #2, you can read it as *with a view toward bringing to [a satisfactory conclusion] [the UN Security Councilˈs consideration of this matter]*, i.e. *with a view toward bringing [the UN Security Councilˈs consideration of this matter] to [a satisfactory conclusion]*.

Comment: I vote “yes” for question 1, with the caveat that language does tolerate (and even employ) redundancies.

Comment: I also nominate @Damkerng T. as official answerer of this question.

Comment: It's verbose, sure. But that's in the nature of international agreements. Don't forget that teams of negotiators with almost certainly *very* high language skills probably spent hours arguing over the exact phrasing. One or other nation probably insisted on the apparently redundant *among other things* to make absolutely sure one of the other things *they had wanted specifically mentioned*  couldn't be dismissed in later negotiations simply because it wasn't explicitly referenced in this communique.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The confusion seems to be a result of a **[heavy NP shift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heavy_NP_shift)** (heavy noun phrase shift).

Consider:

> *with a view toward **bringing it to** a conclusion.*
>   *with a view toward **bringing to** a conclusion **it**.**
>   <sub>* denotes incorrect usage</sub>

We wouldn't move *it* to the end of the sentence because *it* is too light. However, in our sentence we instead have *the UN Security Council's consideration of this matter*, which is a heavy NP (noun phrase), so it can be shifted to the end.

> *with a view toward **bringing to** [a satisfactory conclusion] **[the UN Security Council's consideration of this matter]**.*

It might be easier to understand the phrase by moving the heavy NP back:

> *with a view toward **bringing [the UN Security Council's consideration of this matter] to** [a satisfactory conclusion].*

With that, it should be easy to see that this heavy NP is simply the "Council's consideration", where "Council" means *the UN Security Council*, and the "consideration" means *the consideration of this matter*, and it's the Council's consideration.

The part *"addressing the UN Security Council resolutions, with a view toward bringing to a satisfactory conclusion the UN Security Councilˈs consideration of this matter"* would refer to such addressing and it means that the addressing would be done with a view toward bringing the Council's consideration to a satisfactory conclusion.

---

As for whether ***including, among other things*** is redundant or not, I would say that it can be considered redundant; however, in my opinion, if we removed the *among other things* part, the addressing would appear to be less important than it currently is, as it appears in the original sentence.

Comment: +1 I think, though, that the role of *among other things* is more than superfluous decoration. In my youth *including* was generally understood to introduce "some but not all members of the set"; but these days I see it used more and more in a comprehensive sense,to introduce "all members of the set". Under the principle that "Anything which can be misunderstood will be",  I'm afraid that prudence now requires a writer to make clear whether the list which follows *including* is partial or complete. This is particularly the case in legal and diplomatic documents.

Comment: Got it; bringing X to Y has been changed to bringing to Y X. bringing to (Y:a satisfactory conclusion) (X:the UN Security Councilˈs consideration of this matter). It is interesting that the to-phrase has been shifted backward. Would you give me a link explaining this issue in a way suitable for learners and some more examples where a Prepositional Phrase might be shifted?

Comment: It might be better to think of this shifting as a "heavy NP shift" than a "to-phrase shift". I'm not sure if I could find it explained in typical grammar books for ELL. And as far as I can tell, there is no specific rule about when a NP is "heavy" enough to allow such shifting. However, I found this [page](http://www.phon.ucl.ac.uk/home/dick/enc2010/articles/heavy-NP-shift.htm), which discusses the shift in plain English. ...

Comment: ... From the page: *A 'heavy' phrase (which need not be an NP) may sometimes be moved to the end of its sentence in order to make it easier to process, even if the normal rules require it to occur earlier.* Also from the same page: *Nobody knows how to define 'heaviness', nor do we really know how to allow this freedom for direct objects but not for indirect objects.*

Answer (score 1):

*Among other things* is more in the nature of semantic fluff, although it is redundant. The existence of "other things" is implied by the use of the word *including*. Otherwise, it might have been phrased like this:

> There would be additional steps in between the initial measures and the final step, *consisting of* addressing the UN Security Council...

So yes, it is redundant. In the context, *among other things* appears to me to be adding useless length to the sentence. It's a misguided attempt at sounding impressive. ("I'll just throw more words at them. They'll never know the difference! Bumblebee. Gorgonzola. Chlorophyll. Soliloquy.")

As to the apostrophe, it is used to indicate a possessive form of "The UN Security Council". The sentence could be correctly re-written like this:

> ...with a view toward bringing to a satisfactory conclusion the Councilˈs consideration of this matter.

Which could then be more plainly be re-written like this:

> ...with the intention of helping the Council to finish their deliberations on the issue.

When the modifiers are stripped, the possessive form of the noun becomes clear. The apostrophe is "correctly" used, in the sense that it is syntactically correct. However, the full extract would be easier to read if it were written like this:

> Additionally, before the final step, there would be an address to the UN Security Council. It would be intended to help the Council conclude their deliberations in a manner that would be satisfactory to all parties.