# What's the grammatical construction of "this book has built into it different ways"?

Tags: word-order

> Most students come to Greek with varying degrees of apprehension. Their enthusiasm often wears down as the semester progresses. This book, therefore, **has built into it different ways** of encouraging them...

How should one understand that part in a bold type grammatically? To my mind what this is trying to say is that the book has different ways of encouraging students built into it. But the author for some reason changes the word order.

Comment: You can understand it as a heavy noun-phrase shift. I discussed it once in one of my answers here: http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/17500/3281.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have discovered the answer.

I suspect the author reversed the normal word order to avoid the verb from being so far after the noun *book*. If we write it the way you and I might expect, it would be

**This book, therefore, has different ways of encouraging them built into it.**

It also avoids splitting the *has* and *built into*, but that is not a necessary thing to avoid.

It is an issue of style, but also of "better writing," at least in some people's mind.